# LM358 - as analog voltage mapper 3.3V to 5V

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, dac

I built a circuit based on ESP8266, MCP41100 digital potentiometer and LM358 op-amp. Its purpose is to use it as 0-5V DAC, but I have the following problem:

I use LM358 as non-invering amplifier. It's connected to 5V from VIN ESP8266 pin, non-inv. input is connected to output of voltage divider made from digital potentiometer, inverting thorough 12k and 22k resistor to output and ground.

For some reason I cannot go above 3.7V on output. Could you tell me how to debug it? Everything except part with amplifier works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LM358 is *not* a rail-to-rail output op-amp, and as such cannot be expected to drive near the rails. The output voltage high (Voh) is specified as 26V with a supply of 30V and a load of 2k (so, 4V below the rail). Therefore you should not expect it to drive anywhere near 5V with a 5V supply.

The easiest solution is to choose a RRIO (rail-to-rail input output) op-amp which is fully specified at 5V (there are many to choose from).

Comment: That's answer I needed! Do you know any of these with same pinout as LM358 in DIP-8 package?

Comment: Sure, pick your favorite manufacturer's parametric tables (or Digikey). Because I like Linear, I pulled up the LT1638, which should out-perform the LM358 in most respects and is available in DIP-8. It's Voh at 5V, no-load, is 4.9V.

Comment: @PiotrBomba Oh, also, keep in mind that if all you want is a 5V DAC, there are chips that do this by themselves, almost all of which will probably outperform your digipot + op-amp solution. For example, MCP4801. Better performance, cheaper, etc.

Comment: @unt128_t Will this MCP4801 work with 3.3v I/O of ESP8266? Maybe, I'll switch to that next time, and now I'll use this LT1638. I don't want to make any big changes to the board I have.

Comment: @PiotrBomba No, but there are plenty of parts that will. You will likely want a part which uses an external reference that can be greater than the digital supply voltage. Or use a level shifter in between.